# Ignore dots and allow + in e-mail addresses in mailgun (regex)

Tags: regex, email, gmail, mailgun

I'm new to mailgun and I'm trying to create a filter for "Matching on variations of the recipient of the email". I want it to work just like gmail. Example:
jondoe@gmail.com, jon.doe@gmail.com and j.o.n.d.o.e@gmail.com are the same accounts. Basically I want to remove dots from addresses.

I also want to add option + at the end of address for forwarding purposes. Example: jonedoe+facebook@gmail.com.

This is a regex for adding + at the end but how do I remove the dots?

```
match_recipient("^chris\+(.*)@example.com$")
```

Actually I have this now:

```
(chris)(@example.com)|(^((.*\.)+.*)@example.com$)|(^(chris)\+(.*)@example.com$)
```

And this will match this variations:

```
chris@example.com
chris+@example.com
chris+d@example.com
chris+3@example.com
chris+d8@example.com
chri.s@example.com
c.hri.s@example.com
c.h.r.i.s+@example.com
c.h.r.i.s+2d@example.com
.chris@example.com
chris.@example.com
```

And won't match these (as it shouldn't):

```
ch5ris@example.com
cchris@example.com
chriu@example.com
chriOs@example.com
chbis@example.com
cchhrriiss@example.com
michael@example.com
```

The only issue now is that it matches names with dots at the beginning and at the end. How do I fix this now?

Comment: Would something like `j\.?o\.?n\.?d\.?o\.?e` fulfill your needs?

Comment: I almost figured it out. Can you maybe help me out with the dots?

Comment: Remove the dots before comparing.

Comment: How do I do that? Can you help me edit the string above or maybe point me to some reading material?